# SQL: Joins vs Denormalization (lots of data)

Tags: sql, join, bigdata

I know, variations of this question had been asked before. But my case may be a little different :-)

So, I am building a site that tracks events. Each event has id and value. It is also performed by a user, which has id, age, gender, city, country and rank. (these attributes are all integers, if it matters)

I need to be able to quickly get answers to two queries:

- get number of events from users with certain profile (for example, males with age 18-25 from Moscow, Russia)
- get sum(maybe avg also) of values of events from users with certain profile -

Also, data is generated by multiple customers, which, in turn, can have multiple source_ids.

Access pattern: data  will be mostly written by collector processes, but when queried (infrequently, by web ui) it has to respond quickly.

I expect LOTS of data, certainly more than one table or single server can handle.

I am thinking about grouping events in separate tables per day (that is, 'events_20111011'). Also I want to prefix table name with customer id and source id, so that data is isolated and can be trivially discarded (purge old data) and relatively easily moved around (distribute load to other machines). 
This way, every such table will have limited amount of rows, let's say, 10M tops.

So, the question is: what to do with user's attributes?

Option 1, normalized: store them in separate table and reference from event tables.

- (pro) No repetition of data.
- (con) joins, which are expensive (or so
  I heard).
- (con) this requires user table and event tables to be on
  the same server

Option 2, redundant: store user attributes in event tables and index them.

- (pro) easier load balancing (self-contained tables can be moved around)
- (pro) simpler (faster?) queries
- (con) lots of disk space and memory used for repeating user attributes and corresponding indexes

Comment: normalise until you measure you have a performance problem.

Comment: How much data do you expect to have in each table (assuming normalized) Also, what RDBMS are you considering using?

Comment: What does "users with certain profile" mean?  And what is the value of an event?

You'll get better answers if you post what you've tried, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data.

Comment: @Catcall, edited question to clarify this. By "profile" I meant something like "males with age 18-25 from Moscow, Russia"

Comment: There is no single answer to this. Books have been written on these problems: some of your requirements are supported by OLTP systems (quick saves, more distribution & fault tolerance), but then others by OLAP systems (Quick aggregation and analysis.)

Comment: @JohnFx Most of my experience is with MySQL, so it is my first choice :-)

If data is normalized, then user table will have estimated average size of 2-10 millions. Event table will hold up to 10 millions as well.

Comment: @JamieF, wait, is there not silver bullet? :-)

Comment: 10M rows is a lot, but it isn't so much that I'd be looking at exotic solutions.

Comment: 10 millions rows is not 'alot'. By today's standards it is relatively small to medium.

Comment: For events, it's not clear whether you're talking about 10 million rows a day, or 10 million rows as an upper estimate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your design should be normalized, you physical schema may end up denormalized for performance reasons.

Is it possible to do both? There is a reason why SQL Server ships with Analysis Server. Even if you are not in the Microsoft realm, it is a common design to have a transactional system for the data entry and day to day processing while a reporting system is available for the kinds of queries that would cause heavy loads upon the transactional system.

Doing this means you get the best of both worlds: a normalized system for daily operations and a denormalized system for rollup queries.

In most cases nightly updates are fine for reporting systems, but it depends on your hours of operation and other factors what works best. I find most 8-5 businesses have more than enough time in the evening to update a reporting system.

Answer (score 4):

Use an OLAP/Data Warehousing approach. That is, store your data in the standard normalized way, but also store aggregated versions of the data that will be queried frequently in separate fact tables. The user queries won't be on real-time data, but it is usually worth it for the performance trade off.

Also, if you are using SQL Server enterprise I wouldn't roll your own horizontal partitioning scheme (breaking the data into days). There are tools built into SQL server to automatically do that for you.

Comment: No, I do not like Microsoft technologies anymore :-)

Comment: You will after you try to partition a table or implement OLAP by hand.

Comment: +1: Open source occasionally scales well, but MS SQL really nails this particular requirement.

Comment: Partitioning is trivial here. OLAP - may be a problem. Most importantly, I run linux servers and don't have lots of money :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please Normalize

use partitions and indexing to balance load